# Visual Studio Setup project is requiring x64 .NET Core Desktop despite targeting x86 platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, setup-project

I have a visual studio setup project which targets x86 as the platform. The application itself and all libraries target AnyCPU. It is a .NET Core 3.1 WPF Desktop Application.

I've also set the prerequisites to .NET Desktop Runtime 3.1.22 [x86] (and I have NOT selected x64).

Despite this, I Get the following message when I run the installer:

[image]

> This setup requires the x64 .NET Core Desktop Runtime version 3.1.0. Please install the .NET Core Desktop Runtime and run this setup again. The .NET Core Desktop Runtime can be obtained from the web.

As a work-a-round, I included x64 in the prerequisites so that it automatically downloads and installs it if it's missing, but is there any way I can avoid the user unnecessarily downloading an extra runtime?

Comment: The warning is correct, you really do require the x64 runtime.  Microsoft has trouble keeping the AnyCPU illusion alive for .NETCore projects that don't use dotnet.exe.  The dlls you get from a build can run on any bitness, but the .exe can not.  It is the apphost, unmanaged code that loads and initializes the CLR, you'll get the x64 flavor of it when your app project targets AnyCPU.  Simply retarget the app project to x86, no need to tinker with the library projects.

Comment: As always, great information @HansPassant - that `AnyCpu` has crushed my soul many times.

Comment: Thanks @Hans, that worked. I didn't retarget the application, but retargeted the publishing profile the setup project uses (which I think effectively does the same thing as both installer files were the same size). If you put that as the Answer, I'll mark it for you.